# RFID <MFRC522.h> won't work with new ARDUINO UNO WiFi REV2

Tags: arduino, nfc, rfid, spi

I followed a basic example for the RFID module on an ARDUINO UNO REV3 and it works great. But when I try to connect it to the new ARDUINO UNO WiFi REV2 it won't work.  The code compiles, but when I scan the NFC badge, nothing is being printed to the console. The NFC module communicates via SPI protocol. Is the SPI connection different on the new Arduino Uno WiFi REV2?

[image]

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN   9    // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_PIN    10    // Configurable, see typical pin layout above

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance

/* Set your new UID here! */
#define NEW_UID {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF}

MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  while (!Serial);     // Do nothing if no serial port is opened (added for Arduinos based on ATMEGA32U4)
  SPI.begin();         // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();  // Init MFRC522 card
  Serial.println(F("Warning: this example overwrites the UID of your UID changeable card, use with care!"));

  // Prepare key - all keys are set to FFFFFFFFFFFFh at chip delivery from the factory.
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;
  }
}

void loop() {

  // Look for new cards, and select one if present
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() || ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial() ) {
    delay(50);
    return;
  }

  // Now a card is selected. The UID and SAK is in mfrc522.uid.

  // Dump UID
  Serial.print(F("Card UID:"));
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
    Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
  } 
  Serial.println();

  // Set new UID
  byte newUid[] = NEW_UID;
  if ( mfrc522.MIFARE_SetUid(newUid, (byte)4, true) ) {
    Serial.println(F("Wrote new UID to card."));
  }

  // Halt PICC and re-select it so DumpToSerial doesn't get confused
  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() || ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial() ) {
    return;
  }

  // Dump the new memory contents
  Serial.println(F("New UID and contents:"));
  mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial(&(mfrc522.uid));

  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the SPI pins are the same?

Comment: No but I can't find the SPI pins for the arduino uno wifi rev 2. I already tried different pin combinations. Maybe the included libraries use other ports as well?